# Given a set of $n$ points in $[0,1)^d$, how do I partition the space into hyperrectangles such that each hyperrectangle contains exactly one point?

Tags: computational-geometry, partitions

I'm new to this forum so I apologize if my question is ill-posed or too general. I have the following problem. Given a set of $n$ points in the unit hypercube, $[0,1)^d$, how can I partition the unit hypercube into $n$ hyperrectangles such that each element of the partition contains exactly 1 point?

I have done some research and came across Voronoi diagrams. These are similar in spirit to what I would like to construct, however in my problem it is critical that the divisions result in hyperrectangles. However, it is not critical that the partition results in "optimal" regions in the sense that all points are closest according to a particular distance metric. I have very little experience in this area and thus may be missing some critical buzz words or language commonly associated with these types of problems.

Even better would if you could point to some MATLAB code that implements such a partitioning algorithm.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use recursion. Divide the cube into two of one lower dimension. If one cube is empty, project the solution of the other cube onto it.  Gerhard "Divide And Conquer Gone Binary" Paseman, 2019.08.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a $k-$d tree could be used. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree): "a $k-$d tree is a binary tree in which every leaf node is a $k$-dimensional point."

---

[image: Wikifig]

          

<sup>Wikipedia image of a $k-$d tree, $k=2$ (2D).</sup>

---

After constructing the tree (code available all over the web),
there would still be a little bit of work remaining to find an enclosing box for each
leaf point $p$. One way would be to climb upward from the leaf $p$ to find the minimum distance (call it $x$) to
the next partition, in each of the $k$ slicing directions--i.e., look at
all the adjacent surrounding cells. 
Then a cube $\pm x$ centered on $p$ will only enclose $p$.

Comment: (I see my suggestion is a more detailed version of Gerhard's comment; overlapping posts.)

Comment: I like this better, as it suggests splitting on a point, which pushes edge cases to the bottom.  Gerhard "Dust First And Then Vacuum" Paseman, 2019.08.23.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joseph, and also to Gerhard above. It looks as though $k-d$ trees may be helpful indeed. I will read up on them and see if I can make some progress.

Comment: Spent some time yesterday teaching myself about kd trees and they turned out to be exactly what I needed. I wrote my own MATLAB code to construct one along with computing the boundaries of each associated region. Thank you again for your help!